# ASP.NET Core 8 MVC : _Layout.cshtml style reference problem

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc, .net-8.0

I´m fairly new to ASP.NET Core 8 MVC application development.

I've been working on a project called `SistemaInventario`. I want to add new styles to the project and notice the following reference:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="~/SistemaInventario.styles.css" asp-append-version="true" />
```

[CSS references](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ssvwH.png)

The thing is, this file does not exist or at least I can't find it... If I remove this line of code, the application loses some style.

Before:

[Index with style](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ldtkh.png)

After:

[Index without style](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HgdWy.png)

Here´s my wwwroot folder:

[Folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HzO7a.png)

I know this is a minor detail but I really want to know why this happens.

Thanks in advance!

I've been looking for some information, but it seems that is a very particular problem.

Comment: In your web project, there should be a folder `wwwroot` - which is what the tilde `~` refers to. So check your `/wwwroot` folder in Visual Studio for that `.css` file. Typically, CSS files would be stored in `/wwwroot/css` and thus referenced as `<link rel="stylesheet" href="~/css/SistemaInventario.styles.css" .....` - but that's just a convention, not a "hard rule".

Comment: I´ve checked the folder, but the file is called "site.css" not "styles.css"

I have the two references on my project: 

link rel="stylesheet" href="~/css/site.css" asp-append-version="true" 
link rel="stylesheet" href="~/SistemaInventario.styles.css" asp-append-version="true"

Comment: What does your browser's dev tools say about loaded files? Is that file seen, or did it get a 404?

Comment: I think I see the problem now... when I comment the "... styles.css" line, the browser does not render the following stylesheet: "_Layout.cshtml.css". I don´t see how is this related.

Comment: Type of ASP.net project?  Blazor? Razor?  Other?

Comment: The order in which stylesheets are referenced matters. Ensure that the `_Layout.cshtml.css` stylesheet is referenced after the `SistemaInventario.styles.css` `stylesheet. Styles` defined later in the stylesheet will take precedence in case of conflicts. In addition, Inspect the network tab in your browser's developer tools. Are both "_Layout.cshtml.css" and "SistemaInventario.styles.css" being requested (even when commented out)? Are they returning any errors?

Answer (score 1):

This is due to Css isolation. Basically when you deploy your app, all the css file on your views (like _Layout.cshtml.css) are put together inside the file NameOfYourApp.styles.css.
You shoul read the following article : https://asp.net-hacker.rocks/2021/05/10/aspnetcore6-08-css-isolation.html or search articles about CSS Isolation.